# Appium: Unable to call start_activity to launch a different app on Android 7.0

Tags: ruby, appium, ui-automation

I have mobile test where I launch my app and eventually it launches Chrome. To launch Chrome I call the start_activity function with an argument for app_package and app_activity. On devices running Android 5.0 and 6.0, Chrome will launch just fine. However, on Android 7.0 it does not launch at all.

```
@@driver.start_activity(app_package: 'com.android.chrome',
                            app_activity: 'org.chromium.chrome.browser.ChromeTabbedActivity')
```

I get the following error:

```
[ADB] Error: Error occured while starting App. Original error: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of null
    at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (../../lib/logging.js:63:13)
    at ADB.callee$0$0$ (../../../lib/tools/apk-utils.js:77:9)
    at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as throw] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
 Error: Error occured while starting App. Original error: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of null
    at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (../../lib/logging.js:63:13)
    at ADB.callee$0$0$ (../../../lib/tools/apk-utils.js:77:9)
    at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as throw] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
[MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Error occured while starting App. Original error: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of null
    at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (../../lib/logging.js:63:13)
    at ADB.callee$0$0$ (../../../lib/tools/apk-utils.js:77:9)
    at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as throw] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: I've been able to work around this issue by launching Chrome through adb with the following  command:

`adb shell am start -n #{app_package_activity[application]} 'com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main'`